# Trouble configuring Scrollspy and SmoothScrolling on my Bootstrap 4.0 Project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm having a lot of trouble getting Bootstrap's Scrollspy to work on my site. Specifically what I would like it for, is so that as the user scrolls down my site, the respective navbar heading in the navbar will be highlighted.

All the sections on my site have "id's" and are properly linked to the navbar code, but for some reason, even though I have put the Scrollspy in the body element:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="baseNav" data-offset="50">,
```

it still does not function as I'd expect it to.

These are the things that I want to work:

1. User scrolls down my site, and the navbar text that corresponds to the section where the user has scrolled to appears highlighted.
2. Be able to link a drop down menu, and one of the dropdown-items to the same id. For example, say I have link on my navbar that says "Fruits", and it has a dropdown menu that appears that has dropdown-items such as "Bananas", "Oranges" and "Apples". When the dropdown menu appears, if the user clicks "Bananas", it should bring them to the "Bananas" section, but also since its the first item in the "Fruits" section, if the user does not access the dropdown menu, then when clicking on "Fruits" in the navbar should still bring them to "Bananas", since it is the first piece of content on the site related to fruits.

I have included my code here and would appreciate your help in debugging this issue.

To the best I could, I pasted my code and added CDN links for my dependencies into this JFiddle. Some of the CSS doesn't work to well since I use SCSS for development: https://jsfiddle.net/04ghwy60/2/

Comment: Why would you expect scrollspy to work if you are hiding the navbar when the user scrolls down? Kinda defeats the whole purpose of scrollspy, doesn't it?

Comment: Not really, its not hiding permanently. As soon as you scroll back up it reappears. I think i answered my own question though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I found writing this into my 'custom.js' works :

```
    // Smooth scrolling
scrollLink.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
  }, 1000 );
});

// Active link switching
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollbarLocation = $(this).scrollTop();

  scrollLink.each(function() {

    var sectionOffset = $(this.hash).offset().top -41; //41 is just a random magic number i found to work best as an offset to get nice division between 'actives'

    if ( sectionOffset <= scrollbarLocation ) {
      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
      $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
    }
  })

})

})
```